# nginx configuration with no trailing slash

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, trailing-slash

I am trying to configure my nginx. I want it to serve a php file:  `dir/index.php`,but do it the way that i can acces it with `localhost/dir` request (with no trailing slash) without invoking `nginx 301 redirect`. I tried all of the solutions found here, however failed. Can you please explain how can i reach this goal? This is my config:

```
server {
access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log combined;
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/mock-api-server.git;
index index.php;

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try_files` to append `/index.php` to the end of the URI. This must be the last parameter to the `try_files` statement as the new URI is processed in a different location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php?$args;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

The second `try_files` statement is to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php). If the new URI does not correspond to a real PHP file, a 404 response is returned.